# How to forward declare a class template?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement the specification pattern.In that, I have a specification abstract class and an overloaded && operator which returns AndSpecification, which is actually derived from Specification class.Now I have the problem of circular dependency b/w AndSpecification and Specification.Specification is a class template so is AndSpecification.

Specification.h

```cpp
//#include "AndSpecification.h"- this creates a problem
template <class T>
class Specification
{
 public:
     Specification()
     {

     }

     virtual ~Specification()
     {

     }
     virtual bool isSatisfied(T *item)=0;
     AndSpecification<T>  operator&&(Specification &other)
     {
         return AndSpecification<T>(*this,other);
     }
};
```

AndSpecification.h

```cpp
#include "Specification.h"

template <class T>

class AndSpecification : public Specification<T>
{
    Specification <T> *first;
    Specification <T> *second;
public:
    AndSpecification(Specification <T> *first,Specification <T> * second);

    // Specification interface
public:
    bool isSatisfied(T *item) override;
};
```

A help would be appreciated.
full code:**https://github.com/princekm/specification.git**

Comment: I think Specification should not depend on AndSpecification.

Comment: Simple solution: make it a free function instead of a member. There is no reason for `Specification` to be aware of the existence of `AndSpecification`. (That these are templates is mostly irrelevant – you would encounter the same issue if they weren't.)

Comment: I understand that.But It let you use operator&&.This was working when all the code were written in  a single file.

Comment: templates dont need to know about each other. You can add a template template parameter to `Specification` and only later you instantiate `Specification<T,AndSpecification>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need forward declaration, and move definition of your method which need both class definition after those classes:

```
// Specification.h
#pragma once
template <class T> class AndSpecification;

template <class T>
class Specification
{
 public:
     Specification() {}

     virtual ~Specification() {}
     virtual bool isSatisfied(T *item)=0;
     AndSpecification<T>  operator&&(Specification &other);
};

#include "Specification.inl"
```

```
// AndSpecification.h
#pragma once

#include "Specification.h"
template <class T>
class AndSpecification : public Specification<T>
{
    Specification <T> *first;
    Specification <T> *second;
public:
    AndSpecification(Specification <T> *first,Specification <T> * second);

    // Specification interface
public:
    bool isSatisfied(T *item) override;
};
```

```
// Specification.inl
#pragma once
#include "Specification.h"
#include "AndSpecification.h"
template <class T>
AndSpecification<T>  Specification<T>::operator&&(Specification &other)
{
    return AndSpecification<T>(this, &other);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jeznnTYbY)

Comment: I still get error. this is the full code "https://github.com/princekm/specification.git"

Comment: Which is the error? Notice that you have `#include "Specification.inl"` in *"AndSpecification.h"* (might be ok though).

Comment: It is working.Thank you.Can you tell me why you moved the operator function in another file?

Comment: `Specification<T>::operator&&` requires that both classes are defined, so should be placed after. The split in file is to allow the `#pragma once` to work correctly. it mimic the regular .cpp file for non-template cases.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declare it:

```
template <class T> AndSpecification;
```

The following is correct (by removing the pure virtual method for the example):

```
template <class T> class AndSpecification;
template <class T>
class Specification
{
 public:
     Specification()
     {

     }

     virtual ~Specification()
     {

     }
//     virtual bool isSatisfied(T *item)=0;
     AndSpecification<T>  operator&&(Specification &other)
     {
         return AndSpecification<T>(*this,other);
     }
};
template <class T>

class AndSpecification : public Specification<T>
{
    Specification <T> *first;
    Specification <T> *second;
public:
    AndSpecification(Specification <T> *first,Specification <T> * second);

    // Specification interface
public:
    bool isSatisfied(T *item) override;
};

class A{};

int main() {
    Specification<A> a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forward declaration (see other answers) you can consider that `Specification` does not necessarily need to know about `AndSpecification`. I mean, its a template anyhow. If you add a template template parameter to `Specifiacation` like this:

```
template <class T,template<typename> class X>
class Specification
{
 public:
     Specification()
     {

     }

     virtual ~Specification()
     {

     }
     virtual bool isSatisfied(T *item)=0;
     X<T>  operator&&(Specification &other)
     {
         return X<T>(*this,other);
     }
};
```

Then only when you instantiate it you need to know both:

```
 #include "Specification.h"
 #incldue "AndSpecification.h"
 template <typename T>
 using Specification_with_And = Specification<T,AndSpecification>;
```